# NSView constraints work on subviews?

Tags: macos, constraints, xcode8, nsview

I'm using Xcode 8.2. I created a custom NSView that I will be adding to various NSViews. However, when I run the app, one of the buttons doesn't honor the trailing space when the window grows. Why not?

Custom subview uses the recently re-introduced springs and struts. Action button should maintain a constant trailing space:
[image: Custom subview]

The view that includes the custom subview also uses the spring and strut mechanism. It is set to expand with the window:
[image: main view]

When the app runs, the custom view frame grows as it should, but the action button is not in the proper place. This is what Xcode shows for the frames:
[image]

I also tried using normal constraints and I got the same results.